# react-native android application crashes without any error log

Tags: react-native

After loading and Downloading the javascript bundles
my react native android application crashes with message
<APP_NAME> keeps stopping.

Is there any way I can see the logs why my app crashes?
React native console does not show any errors[image: capture of console]

Answer (score 0):

Use android studio to open your app and check the log or using `adb logcat` command.